# Render conditionally header in react native

Tags: react-native, conditional-statements, react-navigation

Hi I'm trying to render the header based on a state. If the state is equals to true I'm showing an avatar image and if it's false I'm rendering a default logo. I've tried doing this based on a ternary operator but it's not working. Here is the code :

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        const { params } = navigation.state;
        return {
          headerTitle: () => (
            <View style ={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',flex:1, flexDirection:'column', overflow:'visible'}}>
                 {this.state.Loaded == false ?
                    <View style ={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',flex:1, flexDirection:'column', overflow:'visible'}}> 
                        <Text style={{marginBottom:15,fontSize:20,fontWeight:"900", color:'#000' }}>Pseudo</Text>
                        <Image
                            style = {styles.avatar}
                            source = {require('../../../Assets/avatar.jpg')} />
                    </View>
                    :
                    <View style={[styles.bandeauHeader, {  } ]}>
                    <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Aide</Text>
                    <Image source={GlobalInclude.LogoIconRose} style={styles.logoBandeauHeader} />
                    </View>
                }      
            </View>
          )
        };
    };
```

Comment: What is the version of react-navigation are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.14.2

Comment: you should consider to use a newer react navigation version if possible - 2.14 seems very old.

Comment: @SauceCurry did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider updating the Navigation to newer version.

First the state is not available inside the static function so you will have to use the navigation params to update the header.

The code should be something like below which you can adopt in your solution.

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    flag: true,
  };

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: navigation.getParam('flag') ? (
        <Text>12323231321</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>67676777</Text>
      ),
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>

        <Button
          title="Update the title"
          onPress={() =>
            this.setState({ flag: !this.state.flag }, () =>
              this.props.navigation.setParams({ flag: this.state.flag })
            )
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```